# App name on testflight is different than iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, testflight

I have created a project with some dummy name, created its provisioning profiles too with com.domainname.appname on Developer portal. I have uploaded few builds on TestFlight. It all goes well. But now I changed the App name over iTunes Connect, But TestFlight still showing the Old name. My Question is, If I uploaded the build for Review on App Store, which name will be there on App Store after Approval of the App ? i.e the old one (Dummy) or the New one.

PS: There is nothing to do with the App name which is showing under the App iCon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes always shows the name as you crated or Updated on iTunes Connect.
If you upload the app for Test Flight with different name, i would suggest you to upload a fresh build with the Updated name.

But i am very sure about name (User will see the name which you created on iTunes).

Comment: I am not sure about it as you are, But I have changed the name of the on iTunes connect and it showing the updated name as well. So You are saying its all good to upload a fresh build for review and it will be available with the Updated name? Right ?

Comment: Yes When you create a new version of your app on iTunes then you can change your app name, and when it will approve then you can see the updated name on iTunes .

Comment: I have changed the name and it is showing updated name, I haven't release any version so far, so I guess I am good to go. right ?

Comment: Great go ahed no worries :)